# Extract all the recurring element of XML using java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, nodes, nodelist

My XML looks like below and I need to extract multiple ID element in 
   an output xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stock>
    <PIdentification>
    <CatalogVersion></CatalogVersion>
    <AccountID></AccountID>
    <CustomerId></CustomerId>
    </ProviderIdentification>
    <Product>
        <ArticleName>Monitors</ArticleName>
        <BaseUnit></BaseUnit>
        <Notes></Notes>
        <ID>11f13e2e-ae97-45b5-a9a9-23fa7f6bb767</ID>
        <ID>b22834c0-a570-4e6b-97c3-5067a14d118d</ID>
        <ID>ed458593-5e1a-4dc1-94f0-a66eeef2dd79</ID>
        <ID>d25584a9-1db2-48cf-9a70-9b81e5a7e7f2</ID>
    </Product>
</Stock>
```

I have used "Nodelist" to extract "ID" but I am getting just one element 
    and not all 4, below is the part of the code:-

```
{   
    Node IDNode = element.getElementsByTagName("ID").item(0);
    IDXml = toStringXml(IDNode , true);
}
```

I am not able to reiterate for look to get all the IDs, please let me 
   know how to get all ID, any help is appreciated.

```
    private static String toStringXml(Node elt, boolean xmlDeclaration) 
    throws TransformerException {
     TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
        .newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

    if(xmlDeclaration)
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(elt);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
    transformer.transform(source, result);

    return result.getWriter().toString();
    }
```

Comment: ```element.getElementsByTagName("Id").item(0)``` indexing at 0 will returen the first id

Comment: typo: `"ID"` != `"Id"`

Comment: Hi, I do not know the syntax to fetch all IDs. Please let me know the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got all id's but you are only looking at first item with `.item(id)`.

Method `getElementsByTageName("ID")` returns you `NodeList` so you can got trough all ids for example like that:

```
File xmlFile = new File("src/main/resources/example.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document element = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName("ID");
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++){
    Node specificIDNode = list.item(i);
    System.out.println(specificIDNode.getTextContent());
}
```

Comment: How do you parse XML? If you print out `list.getLength()` is it just 1?

Comment: @Sahilkhan Tested it and it does work, also added the parsing part to the answer. There might be problem in your `toStringXml` method.

Comment: Hi,list.getLength() is 4 and toStringXml() mehod is pasted above

Answer (score 0):

You have malformed XML displayed in your question. Unclosed `<PIdentification>` tag on the row 3.

Correct XML code should look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stock>
    <ProviderIdentification>
        <CatalogVersion></CatalogVersion>
        <AccountID></AccountID>
        <CustomerId></CustomerId>
    </ProviderIdentification>
    <Product>
        <ArticleName>Monitors</ArticleName>
        <BaseUnit></BaseUnit>
        <Notes></Notes>
        <ID>11f13e2e-ae97-45b5-a9a9-23fa7f6bb767</ID>
        <ID>b22834c0-a570-4e6b-97c3-5067a14d118d</ID>
        <ID>ed458593-5e1a-4dc1-94f0-a66eeef2dd79</ID>
        <ID>d25584a9-1db2-48cf-9a70-9b81e5a7e7f2</ID>
    </Product>
</Stock>
```

And in this case, code, provided by @Penguin74 displays all IDS from your xml (check the picture below).

[image: demo]

Comment: Hi @rafael, I have posted one more question, where I have to extract an element from XML.
"Need to extract element for calculation"

Comment: @Sahilkhan You've got the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60395080/12576990

Comment: @Sahilkhan Also, don't work with xml like a text. Use XML DOM Parser (or StAx parser) to parse xml structure and work with this structure. If you don't understand how does xml parser work, google for it. There are plenty of information about it.

Comment: Hi @Rafael, Thank you! as suggested I used DOM parser and issue is resolved.